# How to mock a part of the response of a GraphQL API?

Tags: next.js, graphql, mocking

I am working on GraphQL APIs for the first time. Need to integrate a change in Model of GraphQL, which is not yet live. New model have some new fields that I need to query and display on the UI with some complex logic & calculations. To simplify let's consider a Model `Book` with below structure:

```
Book{
   Title,
   Author,
   Price, //new field
   Discount //new field
}
```

Now I need to perform some calculation on it and display some output on UI(using Next.js). If I change the query I get 400 from server. And If I try to hard code its response, it would be a complex implementation.

I tried to search for the solution but [Mocking of Apollo](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/testing/mocking/) needs to be implemented on Backend, which is not in my control and hard-coding makes my code very complex. Is there a way I can modify the response without any changes to my system? I can change the operation name and query temporarily but URL will be changed for all other calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO!
You can use a combination of 2 HTTP rules in [Requestly](https://requestly.com).

1. Modify your request to remove those extra parameters you pass. This will allow you to modify query in your system and yet not get any error response.
2. Modify the response to add required parameters to the original response.

For your example:

**Request Modification to Avoid Error**

1. Create a Modify Request Rule - [Documentation Link](https://developers.requestly.io/http-rules/modify-request-body/)
2. Use your GraphQL API endpoint as Source Condition.
3. In Request Body select Programmatic. And use below logic to filter the operation name and modify query.

```js
function modifyRequestBody(args) { //default function of Requestly Template
  const { method, url, body, bodyAsJson } = args;
  // Change request body below depending upon request attributes received in args

  if (bodyAsJson.operationName == "getBooks") { \\assuming operationName is getBooks.
    bodyAsJson.query = "query getBooks {\n  book {\n    author\n    title\n  }\n}";
  }
  return bodyAsJson;
}
```

**Response Modification to temporarily get dummy values**

1. Create new Modify API Response Rule & select GraphQL under resource type. - [Documentation Link](https://developers.requestly.io/http-rules/modify-response-body/)
2. Use GraphQL Endpoint as Source Condition.
3. Under GraphQL Operation enter key and value as 'operationName' and 'getBooks' respectively.
4. In Response Status you can modify if you want to change otherwise it will retain original request status which should come 200 as we have already fixed the request.
5. In Response Body select Dynamic and use below logic to modify your response.

```js
function modifyResponse(args) {
  const {method, url, response, responseType, requestHeaders, requestData, responseJSON} = args;
  // Change response below depending upon request attributes received in args
  responseJSON.data.book.forEach(function(book){
    book.price = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100); \\ returns a random number between 0 & 100
    book.discount = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    return book;
  })
  
  return responseJSON;
}
```

This way you can develop your frontend code with new changes to the model and just turn off the rules when your backend is ready. Pro Tip - Put these rules in a group to manage easily.

Hope this helps.

NOTE: I am one of the maintainers of Requestly!

Comment: Wow such a simple solution! Thanks for making a great tool.